# Add symbol every 2 bytes

Tags: bash, sed

I have a string `20000024ff3dbf50` that I would like to convert it like: `20:00:00:24:ff:3d:bf:50`, I've tried with `sed`:

`echo 20000024ff3dbf50 | sed 's/\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1:\2:\3:\4:\5:\6:\7:\8/'`

but it's a little ugly.

Comment: Surely there's a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two substitutions:

```
echo "20000024ff3dbf50" | sed 's/../&:/g;s/.$//'
```

Results:

```
20:00:00:24:ff:3d:bf:50
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 20000024ff3dbf50 | grep -o .. | paste -d ':' -s -
```

Grep with -o splits the input to 2 chars per line;
paste uses delimiter ':' to pad them [-s]erially

Answer (score 1):

You could also use GNU awk auto-splitting for this:

```
echo 20000024ff3dbf50 | awk '$1=$1' FPAT=.. OFS=:
```

Output:

```
20:00:00:24:ff:3d:bf:50
```